# Tag synonym - Template/Templates

Tags: discussion

Seeing as the posts for these two tags are very similar (and to the best of my knowledge refer to the same tag) I propose that we synonym `[templates] -> [template]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. :)

> Satisfying the 30 character limit …

Comment: Ah cool. That was quick. Thanks :)